# using var in the other function for select in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, select, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor and this code is for a button. I store xml in Dom. I am trying to use the xml in the other function for a select box. The select box's code is similar with this button code. when I hit a list in the select box, i want to see the word between `<chr>` and `</chr>`. I do not want to put `<chr>` in a option.

```
type: 'button',
id: 'btnFind',
align: 'left',
style: 'width:100%',
label: 'add',
onClick: function () {
    var y = this.getDialog();
    var value1 = y.getValueOf('replace', 'chgWord');
    var value2 = y.getValueOf('replace', 'title');
    var xml = "<channel><title>" + value1 + "</title><chr>" + value2 + "</chr></channel>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("title");
    $("#cke_119_select").append("<option value='" + $title.text() + "'>" + $title.text() + "</option>");
    $title = $xml.find("chr");
```

this is a code for selecbox:

```
type: 'hbox',
widths: ['200px', '90px'],
children: [{
    type: 'select',
    label: '약어 LIST :',
    size: 5,
    style: 'width:100%',
    labelLayout: 'horizontal',
    id: 'list',
    items: [],
    onClick: function () {

        selValue = $("#cke_119_select option:selected").val();
        selText = $("#cke_119_select option:selected").text();
        selIndex = $("#cke_119_select option").index($("#cke_119_select option:selected"));
        selBox = $("#cke_119_select");
        selOption = selBox.attr("options");

        var y = this.getDialog();
        var value1 = y.setValueOf('replace', 'chgWord');
        value1.setValue(selValue);
```

Comment: what is your question? Please be specific since code alone makes little sense

Comment: I want to use "var" in the other function. Since the code for parseXML only work in the function for the button, I can not use "var xml" int the other function for select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` is a JavaScript keyword and is independent from where it is being used and you can use it as you wish.

> If you're in a function then "var" will create a local variable, "no var" will look up the scope chain until it finds the variable or hits the global scope (at which point it will create it).
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470494/694325

You already even have `var` in both of the onClick functions, so you indeed can and Do use it already.

```
var xml = "<channel><title>" + value1 + "</title><chr>" + value2 + "</chr></channel>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("title");
```

That for example creates four variables at the same time, like `var a=1,b=2,c=3;`

```
var y = this.getDialog();
```

That is exactly the same way of declaring variables. Your issue is not with `var` here.

It looks like you want to set the value/values for a richCombo. Maby you could try functions like `var theValue = this.getValue();` and `this.setValue("New Value");` inside the onClick. Also, `onClick: function ( value ) { ... alert(value); ...}` might be useful. If you want to change the items try accessing `this._.items` in the onClick. I can't help you more without knowing more on exactly what you are trying, sorry!

Comment: Thank yuo so much. It's so helpful for me. I used localStorage to do this. you answer gave me more information!

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a `var` outside of the first function you can use the variable in the second

```
var xml;

function one(){
  xml= "<channel><title>" + value1 + "</title><chr>" + value2 + "</chr></channel>";

}

function two(){
  /* can access xml here that was set in function one*/
}
```